# JFolder::create: Could not create directory in all pages

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

i installed joomla2.5 and see this error in all administrator pages even login page!

```
JFolder::create: Could not create directory
```

i did every solution i found like changing the tmp and logs path to '/logs' or './logs/' but not worked.
folders permission is 755.
any one can help me ?

Comment: It could be due to folder ownership. Check with your host to see if there are any issue with ownership

Comment: for change the permission of file i must reset the ownership. but the problem is that default permission is 755 and default ownership is 'apache'. i must change this default to solve my problem. thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFolder::create: Could not create directory - Joomla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802419/jfoldercreate-could-not-create-directory-joomla/28871387#28871387)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 755 permission gives the group/others the read and execute permissions in the directory.

This means, that non-group members cannot create new directories.

Make sure that the owner of the directory is the user that the server is running as.

To figure out which user that is, you can use:

> $ echo $(ps axho user,comm|grep -E "httpd|apache"|uniq|grep -v "root"|awk 'END {if ($1) print $1}')

And if does not provide the desired result, simply explore the output of:

> $ ps aux | grep -E "httpd|apache" | grep -v -E "root|grep"

You can find which group it belongs to by using:

> $ groups [userName]

Next, change the owner of the joomla folder. I am using `www-data` as an example:

> # chown -R www-data:www-data path/to/your/joomla/root/dir

PS,

lines preceded by `$` can be executed by a normal user, lines preceded by `#` require root privilege - you can use `sudo` or your favorite method.

Comment: @Mohsen, You are welcome. Once you confirm that an answer is indeed valid, it is recommended to accept it in order to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below variable to in your configuration file(`configuration.php`) as shown.

```
public $log_path = '/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/tmp';
```

Also make sure that these folder has the folder permission 755.

[Read more](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=252418)

[JFolder::create: Could not create directory - Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802419/jfoldercreate-could-not-create-directory-joomla/15802420#15802420)