# Joomla - Plugin available in more languages

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, multilingual, joomla-extensions

I need to know and how, if I can put my custom joomla-plugin v2.5 in multiple languages.

Actually, when I upload my Plugin on the Extension Manager, I can't install and joomla say: Unable to write file.

Help please :)

Comment: That looks like a permissions problem on the plugins folder.

Comment: @Mike W is saying right

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to folder permissioin.

[Why can't you install any extensions?](http://docs.joomla.org/Why_can%27t_you_install_any_extensions?)

[JFolder::create: Could not create directory - Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802419/jfoldercreate-could-not-create-directory-joomla/15802420#15802420)